# Is it fine to put main things directly in preload.js without using ipc?

Tags: javascript, electron

In electron,

If I use ipc and preload script

preload.js:

```js
const { contextBridge, ipcRenderer } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  doSomething: () => {
    ipcRender.send("DO_SOMETHING");
  }
});
```

and main.js:

```
(...)

const something = require("some-module-for-node");
ipcMain.on("DO_SOMETHING", () => {
  something.doSomething();
});
```

If just directly put main process codes in preload.js without ipc,

preload.js:

```
const something = require("some-module-for-node");
const { contextBridge } = require("electron");

contextBridge.exposeInMainWorld("api", {
  doSomething: () => {
    something.doSomething();
  }
});
```

Is it fine to use like second example?

Comment: It depends on `some-module-for-node`. Some modules you can use in the renderer, some you can't. Just try it and see if it works.

Comment: @Joshua Of course, it's module for the main process. 
Plus, `nodeIntegration` is false so cannot use `require` in renderer process.

Comment: Specifically what module are you trying to use?

Comment: [ytdl-core](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ytdl-core) <- This module

Comment: What makes you say this is a "main process module"? It looks to me like a regular Node.js module that can work in either process

Comment: @aabuhijleh I set `nodeIntegration` false for the security, like I said before